# Different way to determine rank of $3\times3$-matrix with parameter by using row transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

For $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the matrix $A$ is given with $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2-a & 1-a & a \\ 1-a & 1-a & 0 \\ 2-2a & 1-a & -(1-a) \end{pmatrix}.$$

For all possible $a$, determine the rank of $A$ by only using row transformations.

One thing that always works would be the Gauss algorithm, but that would be relatively cumbersome as it requires a lot of case differentiations when dividing by something that includes an $a$.

So my question is: Is there a way to solve this problem with row transformations without using the effective but laborious Gauss algorithm?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify Gauß' algorithm, borrowing techniques used for the computation of determinants:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} 2-a & 1-a & a \\ 1-a & 1-a & 0 \\ 2-2a & 1-a & -(1-a) \end{bmatrix}&\rightsquigarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1-a & 1-a & 0 \\ 2-2a & 1-a & -(1-a)\\2-a & 1-a & a \end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1-a & 1-a & 0 \\ 0 & -(1-a) & -(1-a)\\2-a & 1-a & a \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align}
Now, if $a\ne 1$, this matrix has the same rank as
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & -1\\2-a & 1-a & a \end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & a \end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & a+1 \end{bmatrix}.
 \end{align}
You can now conclude (not forgetting to examine the case $a=1$).

Answer (score 1):

Gauss is very comfortable here; just switch column two and one.  Consider then the case $a=1$; here the rank is $1$.  Otherwise you will be done in two very easy steps without considering further cases.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the answer. But wouldn't switching columns be considered a column transformation and thus "illegal" in this exercise, as only row transformations are allowed?

Comment: Concerning the rank it's a legal move . :)